# Web Help for a ASP.net 3.5 web application

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, web-applications

I need to create User help for my web application. I know there are several expensive tools to create webhelp like Framemaker or Robohelp.

Is there any opensource easy to use ones you can think of?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Sandcastle](http://www.codeplex.com/Sandcastle)? Microsoft builds MSDN with it. It depends on your needs I suppose, but it generates HTML output. If you think it might suit your purpose, [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/SHFB) as well. It's basically a GUI to the program.

Answer (score 0):

check out this link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help_authoring_tool.

A Help Authoring Tool or HAT is a software program used by technical writers to create online help manuals.  This tool was mentioned as an alternative or competitor to the framemaker tool.

Answer (score 0):

Here another possible tool:

http://www.helpsmith.com/quickinfo.php?acam=helpsmith

Answer (score 0):

Also check out [Docu](http://docu.jagregory.com/)

A documentation generator for .Net that isn't complicated, awkward, or difficult to use. Given an assembly and the XML that's generated by Visual Studio, docu can produce an entire website of documentation with a single command.